# Ant release Lightning page with components from managed package

Tags: ant, package, flexipages, ant-script

I am trying to release my changes from Sandbox to Production using Ant.

I have created a page using the Lightning App Builder containing components from a managed package.

When releasing the page, the page is empty in production.

How to include them in my ant script so the components get released?

When I inspect my flexipage retrieved from sandbox using ant, it contains no components in the XML.

*I have added the included lightning components in my unpackaged.xml in the AuraDefinitionBundle type.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    ...
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <members>TASKRAY_LTNG__trMyProjects</members>
        ...
        <name>AuraDefinitionBundle</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>FlexiPage</name>
    </types>
    ...
    <version>42.0</version>
</Package>
```

Comment: It is possible to move flexiPages and auraBundles between environments using metadata api/ant. Can you please put more details? Issue could be in a typo at package.xml (it is case sensitive btw)

Comment: I have added part of the unpackaged.xml to the question

Comment: Is TaskRay installed in production? You won't be able to migrate the managed components themselves.

Comment: Yes, TaskRay is installed in production, the components can be added manually to the pages in production. But each time I run my ant script the components are removed from pages.

Comment: Does your `FlexiPage` component definition in source sandbox consist of all details that you expect to be migrated?

Comment: The FlexiPage in the Sandbox contains all the components I want in Production, but once I retrieve my FlexiPage using Ant, the components are not added to the XML. So obviously, they are not released to Production.